# Quais as formas de criar uma tag?

Tags: suporte, tags

Existe uma forma de criar uma *tag* sem ser no momento que esta criando uma pergunta? Procurei por algum botão na área de *tags* mas não encontrei nenhum com este objetivo, consegui criar uma *tag* somente quando estava fazendo uma pergunta, e não encontrei uma *tag* que gostaria de usar então a criei naquele momento (digitando no input de *tags* abaixo da pergunta) porém ela ficou sem wiki e sem resumo naquele momento.

Comment: Estou sem tempo para uma resposta completa. A resposta curta é que o único jeito de criar tag é associando ela a uma pergunta. Tags sem perguntas são deletadas pelo sistema, conforme pode ver aqui: [É possível excluir tags com erro de digitação?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1263/3117)